# exact sub string match using jQuery is not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I have the below drop down in my HTML

```
<select name="sel_id" id="sel_id" multiple="yes">
    <option value="100">CLOSING CLERK - FirstName Last Name</option>
    <option value="101">CLOSING COORDINATOR - FirstName Last Name</option>
    <option value="102">CLOSING CLERK SECOND - FirstName Last Name</option>
    <option value="103">CLOSING CLERK THIRD - FirstName Last Name</option>
</select>
```

I need a jquery selector to find an option element (drop down option element of the multi select box) which contains an exact substring of "CLOSING CLERK". And then I need to select that particular `option` in this drop down box. So here it should find and select the first option element only and not third and fourth ones.

Please note that it is not necessary to have this order for the above option elements.

I tried the below jQuery but no luck.

```
$('#sel_id').filter(function (index) {
    return $(this).text().split(' -') === "CLOSING CLERK";
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: no , I cannot use option values(like 100,101 etc..). I need to do this by option text only. Is there any way?. Also I tried .split(' -')[0].trim() === "" but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is incorrect, You need to use `filter()` on `options`. The `split()` method returns an array so use indexer to access first array element and compare it.

Additionally, Use `.prop(key, value)` to set the `selected` property.

```js
jQuery("#sel_id").change(function(event) {
  jQuery(this).find('option').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text().split(' - ')[0].trim() === "CLOSING CLERK";
  }).prop('selected', 'selected');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel_id" id="sel_id" multiple="yes">
  <option value="100">CLOSING CLERK - FirstName Last Name</option>
  <option value="101">CLOSING COORDINATOR - FirstName Last Name</option>
  <option value="102">CLOSING CLERK SECOND - FirstName Last Name</option>
  <option value="103">CLOSING CLERK THIRD - FirstName Last Name</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/no74g2rb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#sel_id option').filter(function(index) { 
  return $(this).text().indexOf("CLOSING CLERK -") >= 0 ;})
      .attr('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel_id" id="sel_id" multiple="yes">

<option value="100">CLOSING CLERK - FirstName Last Name</option>

<option value="101">CLOSING COORDINATOR - FirstName Last Name</option>

<option value="102">CLOSING CLERK SECOND - FirstName Last Name</option>

<option value="103">CLOSING CLERK THIRD - FirstName Last Name</option>

</select>
```